# Cannot add constraint to DataTable 'srgbClr' which is a child table in two nested relations

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, constraints

I have below XML file. I am trying to read it in C# code using below function and it throws an error -

**DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(FileName);**

"Cannot add constraint to DataTable 'srgbClr' which is a child table in two nested relations".

Also note that the same code is working on another machines and it gives error on one specific machine. Database pointed to all the machines are same.

Also, there is no DataTable which has name assigned as 'srgbClr'.

Do this have any solution ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<CaptainVesselDetails>
  <Header>
    <VesselId>236</VesselId>
    <ExportFileTypeId>8</ExportFileTypeId>
    <ExportDate>2016-04-15</ExportDate>
    <VersionNumber>1884</VersionNumber>
  </Header>
  <MST_Vessel_Captain>
    <CaptainId>1084</CaptainId>
    <TitleId>3</TitleId>
    <CaptainName>TEST</CaptainName>
    <NationalityId>25</NationalityId>
    <DateofBirth>1968-01-09</DateofBirth>
    <CreatedDate>2014-09-26</CreatedDate>
    <ModifiedBy>84</ModifiedBy>
    <ModifiedDate>2016-04-15</ModifiedDate>
  </MST_Vessel_Captain>
  <MST_Vessel_Captain_History>
    <CaptainHistoryId>3011</CaptainHistoryId>
    <SignIn>2016-03-31</SignIn>
    <SignOff>2016-07-29</SignOff>
    <RecruitmentOffice>Ukraine</RecruitmentOffice>
    <VesselId>236</VesselId>
    <CaptainId>1084</CaptainId>
  </MST_Vessel_Captain_History>
  <MAP_Vessel_Login>
    <VesselLoginId>2525</VesselLoginId>
    <CaptainId>1084</CaptainId>
  </MAP_Vessel_Login>
</CaptainVesselDetails>
```

Comment: To enable people to assist, you should add your c# code as well

Comment: **DataSet ds = new DataSet();**

**ds.ReadXml(FileName);**

Comment: Where are you getting the xml data?  Make sure you have the correct filename.

Comment: In one application I am writing the data in xml format and I am reading it in another application. I have checked the condition whether file exists or not so that is not the issue. @jdweng

Comment: Did you actually open the file to make sure it was the same XML that you wrote?

Comment: Yes, XML is correct. Also, it can be opened in the XML editor.

Comment: Maybe the latest code isn't on both machines.  Check timestamp on executables files on both machines and compare to files in debug, release, x86 folders.  How did you install software on non working machine?  Do both machines have same version of Net Library with same updates?  Did you publish and install?